# Работа команды SCASB

Tags: ассемблер

Есть вот такой исходник для проверки работы команды. Компилирую и смотрю, что происходит с регистрами флагов. Они не меняются.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none   ; case sensitive

.data
    character db 's'

.code
start:
    mov ax,ds
    mov es,ax
    mov al,'s'
    lea di,character
    scasb
end start
```

Можете подсказать почему с регистрами флагов ничего не происходит и предназначены ли эта команда для одиночного вызова вообще? Ибо нахожу примеры только с оператором repne перед ней.

**UPD** Добавив *nop* заметил, что отладчик подвисает на строке scasb. Как такое может происходить? Отладчик выводит следующую ошибку: **Access violation when reading [000020000]**

Comment: Данную команду вполне допустимо использовать без префиксов rep*. Согласно одному из множества найденных в сети справочников, команда воздействует на флаги AF, CF, OF, PF, SF и ZF. Прямо сейчас проверить работоспособность приведенного кода не могу. Могу предположить, что вы смотрите в отладчике состояние флагов до вызова данной команды. Попробуйте добавить в конец программы nop и посмотреть состояние флагов, когда счетчик команд указывает уже на него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо [[@sys_dev](/users/14618/sys_dev)](/users/14618/sys_dev). В мануале есть следующее примечание:

*In 64-bit mode, only 64-bit (RDI) and 32-bit (EDI) address sizes are supported. In non-64-bit mode, only 32-bit (EDI) and 16-bit (DI)
address sizes are supported.*

То есть нужно изменить операцию **lea di,character** на **lea edi,character**. Спасибо всем кто отозвался.

Comment: Примечание в мануале не об этом. Причина ошибок в том, что программа скомпилиована для 32-битного режима, а код взят из примера для 16-битного режима. Поэтому и нужно использовать edi вместо di и не нужны манипуляции с сегментными регистрами.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую скачать мануал Intel Volume 2 он в двух частях a и b. Это наилучшее средство от сомнений по работе машинных инструкций Intel-x86-64 архитектуры